# ssim as custom loss function in autoencoder (keras or/and tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

I am currently programming an autoencoder for image compression. From a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51010963/keras-custom-loss-pure-python-without-keras-backend) I have now final confirmation that I cannot use pure Python functions as loss functions neither in Keras nor in tensorflow. (And I am slowly beginning to understand why ;-)

I would like to do some experiments using the [ssim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_similarity) as a loss function and as a metric. Now it seems I might be lucky. There is already an implementation of it in tensorflow, see: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/ssim

tf.image.ssim(
    img1,
    img2,
    max_val
)

In addition, *bsautermeister* kindly provided an implementation here on stackoverflow: [SSIM / MS-SSIM for TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051451/ssim-ms-ssim-for-tensorflow).

My question now is: how would I use it as a loss function, with the mnist data set? The function does not accept a tensor but only two images. And, will the gradient be automatically computed? From what I understand it should if the function is implemented in tensorflow or keras backend.

I would be very gratefull for a minimum working example (MWE) on how to use any of the previously mentioned ssim implementations as a loss function either in keras or tensorflow.

Maybe we can use my MWE for an autoencoder provided with my previous question:
[keras custom loss pure python (without keras backend)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51010963/keras-custom-loss-pure-python-without-keras-backend)

If it is not possible to glue my keras autoencoder together with the ssim implemenations would it be possible with an autoencoder directly implemented in tensorflow? I have that, too, and can provide it?

I am working with python 3.5, keras (with tensorflow backend) and if necessary tensorflow directly.
Currently I am using the [mnist dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51010963/keras-custom-loss-pure-python-without-keras-backend) (the one with the numbers).

Thanks for any help!

(P.S.: Several people seem to be working on similar things. An answer to this post may also be useful for [Keras - MS-SSIM as loss function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48744945/keras-ms-ssim-as-loss-function))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot serve with Keras but in plain TensorFlow you just switch the L2 or whatever cost with the SSIM results like

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def fake_img_batch(*shape):
    i = np.random.randn(*shape).astype(np.float32)
    i[i < 0] = -i[i < 0]
    return tf.convert_to_tensor(np.clip(i * 255, 0, 255))


fake_img_a = tf.get_variable('a', initializer=fake_img_batch(2, 224, 224, 3))
fake_img_b = tf.get_variable('b', initializer=fake_img_batch(2, 224, 224, 3))

fake_img_a = tf.nn.sigmoid(fake_img_a)
fake_img_b = tf.nn.sigmoid(fake_img_b)

# costs = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(fake_img_a, fake_img_b, reduction=tf.losses.Reduction.MEAN)
costs = tf.image.ssim(fake_img_a, fake_img_b, 1.)
costs = tf.reduce_mean(costs)

train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01).minimize(costs)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(costs))
    for k in range(500):
        _, l = sess.run([train, costs])
        if k % 100 == 0:
            print('mean SSIM', l)
```

To check whether an operation has gradients (implemented) is straight-forward:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def fake_img_batch(*shape):
    i = np.random.randn(*shape).astype(np.float32)
    i[i < 0] = -i[i < 0]
    return tf.convert_to_tensor(np.clip(i * 255, 0, 255))

x1 = tf.convert_to_tensor(fake_img_batch(2, 28, 28, 3))
x2 = tf.convert_to_tensor(fake_img_batch(2, 28, 28, 3))


y1 = tf.argmax(x1)  # not differentiable -> no gradients
y2 = tf.image.ssim(x1, x2, 255) # has gradients

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(tf.gradients(y1, [x1]))  # will print [None] --> no gradient
    print(tf.gradients(y2, [x1, x2]))  # will print [<tf.Tensor 'gradients ...>, ...] --> has gradient
```

Comment: Firstly, many thanks. This is very helpful already. You clarified the gradient question for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is still something I don't quite understand. Using mnist=input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data", one_hot=True) and print(mnist.train.num_examples,mnist.test.num_examples,mnist.validation.num_examples) I get (55000,784) (55000,10) For the fake images you are using a proper tensor with (2, 224, 224, 3) (2, 224, 224, 3). But tf.image.ssim is only designed for images? What am I missing here? I cannot get the code to work with mnist. Can you clarify on how dimensions go together?

Comment: You can *only* apply SSIM to two images, so you have to reshape the 784-input to [28, 28, 1]. And please do [not forget](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try again. I'll post the MWE as soon as I get it to work.

Comment: What is the function of the `tf.reduce_mean()` line here?  Is the original `costs` giving a tensor of ssims across a batch, and the next line averaging them to a single batch mean ssim value?